# .htaccess - I want to add extra get variable to the end

Tags: .htaccess

Basically I want to be so show a version of cms with banner and menu turned off.

So adminlite would redirect user to admin/ with a extra get variable on the end like cms=lite

Here is the code

```
RewriteRule ^adminlite\??(.*)$ /oxbridge/admin$1 [QSA] [L]
```

but every time I try to add to the end it stop working e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^adminlite\??(.*)$ /oxbridge/admin$1&cms=lite [QSA] [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Query-String is not part of the URL in the RewriteRule. So you have to do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^adminlite(.*)$ /oxbridge/admin$1?cms=lite [QSA,L]
```

e.g. `/adminlite?foo=bar` goes to `/oxbridge/admin?foo=bar&cms=lite`

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be [QSA,L] rather than [QSA][L]